# Difference between manga and light novel written by same author

Tags: hentai-ouji-to-warawanai-neko

If both manga and light novel are written by the same author will there be any difference between them? I did a little digging in the internet for it, but all I got was the general difference between manga and light novel.

TBH, I am asking this question because it seems that English translation for the light novel "The Pervert Prince and the Stony Cat" aka "Henneko" written by Sou Sagara has been abandoned(I can't find better words than this). But the same author wrote the story of the manga version of the aforementioned LN and it's translation is finished and it also has ended publishing.

It's true that the aforementioned series is not really known to many people. Since I have an affinity to the ecchi genre, that's how I bumped upon this series.

Answer (score -1):

A manga is a comic book or graphic novel - **a story told in sequential art**.
A light novel is a prose book with some illustrations. Called "light" because the content tends to be easy-reading and the size is small and portable.

I googled it myself and the first search result was this below:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-manga-and-light-novels 
And honestly you won't find a better answer to this. Question is pretty much the same as well. You just added the same author clause.

By looking at the timing of manga and light novel(almost the same) i can just say that, either he wasn't ready for someone to work on his creation or he wanted to expand his fanbase while he was onboard to earn money or fame or even just the simple logic "like providing fans his content as per his vision". He, decided to write both novel and manga.

Comment: The OP is asking about the difference of the light novel and manga version for a specific series, not about light novels and manga in general. Take note of the difference.

Comment: @W.Are i did cover it in the last para, it was all about the specific series

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see how it answers what the OP wants to know. The OP is asking differences between the manga and light novel of Henneko, not why the author decided to write both novel and manga. There is no mention at all of said differences, if there are any, like how the story in the manga deviated from the light novel, if it did.

Comment: unfortunately for  me you edited the question. Previously it seemed like he had read them by the way he describer the series. i wrote what i felt like. You're welcome to answer if you don't like my answer.  Thanks for the downvote anyway. OP hasn't responded to it so i am not gonna edit that on your understanding of the question.

Comment: I merely restructured the paragraphs :/ I only changed the title since the body of the question is more of the OP asking about Henneko and the differences between its manga version and light novel version. I can roll back the edit and it does not change the fact that you still did not list any differences between the light novel and manga version of Henneko. I know that I am welcome to answer but as I have not read both the LN and manga, I will defer to someone who have actually read both.

Comment: 'I did a little digging in the internet for it but all I got was the general difference between manga and light novel.' Clearly, the OP found this information but took the time to ask here since he/she is interested in a particular series: Henneko. Questions getting edited is not a problem as you can look at the revision history and verify if it did change. If you won't take suggestions, I can't do anything about that. Have a good day.

Comment: I have got the ans to my ques in reddit. It seems that the series is the same in both LN and manga, no difference. You all took my ques wrongly.